# The placeholder text doesnt disappear

Tags: css, javascript

I've setup a newsletter form using Mailpoet. However, no matter what I've tried, the placeholder text doesnt disappear upon clicking the input field. I tried adding the following css code, however, it still does'nt work

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 18- */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* oldIE */
```

My website is new.lollipopnursery.ae

Answer (score 0):

I believe this script will work for you:

```
$('[placeholder]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('placeholder', $this.attr('placeholder'))
         .focus(function(){$this.removeAttr('placeholder');})
         .blur(function(){$this.attr('placeholder', $this.data('placeholder'));});
});
```